# Watson Visual Recognition in Android

Tags: java, android, watson, visual-recognition

I am developing an app in which my requirement to select an image from the SD card and send in to IBM Waston Visual Recognition service to identify the content in the image. I am doing like this..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
} 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == MainActivity.this.RESULT_OK && null != data){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn,null,null,null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        analizarImagen(picturePath);
    }
}

private void analizarImagen(String path){
    File image = new File(path);
    System.out.println(path);

    VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20);
    service.setApiKey("api-key");

    ClassifyImagesOptions options = new ClassifyImagesOptions.Builder()
            .images(image)
            .build();
    VisualClassification result = service.classify(options).execute();
    System.out.println(result.toString());

}
```

But when I select an image, the application crashes

Error:

```
02-02 03:43:49.720 3355-3355/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/23 }} to activity {com.cucea.mauricio.visual/com.cucea.mauricio.visual.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                          Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
                                             at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
                                             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                             at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296)
                                             at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243)
                                             at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
                                             at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:179)
                                             at com.cucea.mauricio.visual.MainActivity.analizarImagen(MainActivity.java:84)
                                             at com.cucea.mauricio.visual.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:68)
                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) 
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting server from main(UI) thread which is not allowed in android. Call your analizarImagen() method in separate thread or async task.

Check this document:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html